# org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils vs org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings

Tags: java, string

Both libraries have few similar methods (eg. `isEmpty`, `isNotEmpty`, `isBlank`, etc.).

In different implementations I have seen I noticed that these methods from both libraries are equally often used.

So my question is - which of `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` and `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings` is better if any? Or in which cases one of them is better? For example, is that better to use `StringUtils.isEmpty` or `Strings.isEmpty`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`. Its a well tested utility class designed to ease out some naive checks required in day to day code writing.

I am not against `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings` but developer of this library might have created `Strings` for internal use only. So you could use this but its generally not preferred.

See the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/Strings.html) of `log4j Strings`

```
Class Strings
org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings

public final class Strings extends Object
    Consider this class private.
See Also:
    Apache Commons Lang
```

Notice the line saying **Consider this class private.**

Comment: +1, just to add that by using log4j you are coupling your classpath with log4j impl, which might not be desirable if you are using slf4j api.

Comment: @rkosegi Agreed.